# Hibernate One To One mapping with Where Clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three Entities Student, Course & StudentCourse. The StudentCourse Entity keeps associations between Student & Course and sets a startDate when that association is created. When the association is no longer active an End Date is updated in the row. I am keeping the associations in this manner to preserve the history. Also there is a check in the backend to ensure that a student at a time will only have one course for which there is an active association i.e., End Date is NULL.

In the Student Entity, I want to use One To One Mapping in Hibernate with a Where clause so that the matching rows in the StudentCourse table are fetched not only on the basis of the studentId but also the where condition specified.

However when I try to get the StudentCourse Hibernate throws an Exception stating that

> org.hibernate.HibernateException More than one row with the given
>   identifier was found

```
@Entity     
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Where(clause = "endDate IS NULL")
    private StudentCourse studentCourse;

    private String name;
}
```

Course Entity:

```
 @Entity     
    public class Course {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        private String name;
    }
```

StudentCourses Entity:

```
@Entity     
    public class StudentCourses {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="studentId", referencedColumnName="id")
        private Student student;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="courseId", referencedColumnName="id")
        private Course course;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date endDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date startDate;
    }
```

And I also checked in StudentCourse there are two entries with the same studentId but one of them has an EndDate. So I am only looking for the one which has no endDate set.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Why do you have two **StudentCourses** Entity classes ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. Take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be working. You can check comments about `Where` annotation in hibernate's `CollectionBinder`, which states it should be used with `OneToMay` and `ManyToMany` field annotation.

You can add where clause to your entity definition under class `StudentCourse`. In this case you always will get entities with endDate different from null. I also think that you could made mistake in your business logic. If you state that `Student` should has **only one** `StudentCourse`, you shouldn't persist many entites like you do. Or maybe what you want to achive is so called "soft delete", when you mark some rows as inactive in your DB and shouldn't be used normally in your logic.

So use studentCourse as collection

```
@OneToMany
@Where(clause = "endDate IS NULL")
private Collection<StudentCourse> studentCourse;
```

or use entity's annotation

```
@Where(clause = "endDate IS NULL")
class StudentCourse {
...
}
```

Comment: I can't use a where above the StudentCourse Entity because If I want to get the history if previous courses enrolled by the student it won't work. Also I can't use oneToMany because when I try to paginate the Students based on the current course  enrolled (using Specification) following exception is thrown 

"Illegal attempt to de-reference path source"